# How to group subarrays and perform conditional calculations?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, conditional-statements, grouping, integer-arithmetic

I need to group my subarray using `product_id` and perform some conditional arithmetic.

If `moving_type` is `1` then the overall `product_number` tally for the current `product_id` should be increased by the `product_number`.  Alternatively, if the `moving_type` is `2` then the overall `product_number` tally should be decreased by the `product_number` value.

This is my input array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [product_id] => 4
            [product_number] => 10
            [moving_type] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [product_id] => 5
            [product_number] => 10
            [moving_type] => 1 // product addition
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
           [id] => 1
            [product_id] => 5
            [product_number] => 2
            [moving_type] => 2 // product minus
        )
)
```

My desired result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [product_id] => 4
            [product_number] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [product_id] => 5
            [product_number] => 8 // as 10-2
         )
)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! You need to make a more expanded issue description, with some small snippets of code and by explicitly explaining bugs

Comment: Your question is missing your coding attempt.  Are you merging the data on `id` and `product_id` or just `product_id` alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most efficiently use temporary keys based on `product_id` to determine if you are performing arithmetic between two values or merely declaring the first occurring value for the `product_id`.

If it is the first occurrence, just slice the first three rows off the row and preserve the keys (that's the `true` part).

If it is not the first occurrence of `product_id`, then you will only need to update the `product_number` element.  Determine the correct operation based on the `moving_type` value -- using that, multiply the `product_number` by either `1` or `-1` and add that generated value to the stored value.

When the loop is finished, you can reindex the resulting array with `array_values()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BYfZf))

```
$array = [
     ['id' => 1, 'product_id' => 4, 'product_number' => 10, 'moving_type' => 1],
     ['id' => 1, 'product_id' => 5, 'product_number' => 10, 'moving_type' => 1],
     ['id' => 1, 'product_id' => 5, 'product_number' => 2, 'moving_type' => 2]
];

foreach ($array as $row) {
    if (!isset($result[$row['product_id']])) {
        $result[$row['product_id']] = array_slice($row, 0, 3, true);
    } else {
        $result[$row['product_id']]['product_number'] += ($row['moving_type'] == 1 ? 1 : -1) * $row['product_number'];
    }
}

var_export(array_values($result));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'product_id' => 4,
    'product_number' => 10,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'product_id' => 5,
    'product_number' => 8,
  ),
)
```

Comment: It's working perfect..........You made my day, thank you, thank you very much #Mick

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `foreach()` loop. Inside it, you could create a new array using `product_id` as key. You could use `*=-1` to change the sign of the `product_number`, and if the key already exists, add the current product_number to the existing one.

```
$array = array(
     array('id' => 1, 'product_id' => 4, 'product_number' => 10, 'moving_type' => 1),
     array('id' => 1, 'product_id' => 5, 'product_number' => 10, 'moving_type' => 1),
     array('id' => 1, 'product_id' => 5, 'product_number' => 2, 'moving_type' => 2)
);

$final = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $pid = $item['product_id'] ;
    if ($item['moving_type'] == 2) $item['product_number'] *= -1;
    unset($item['moving_type']);

    if (!isset($final[$pid])) { $final[$pid] = $item ; }
    else {
        $final[$pid]['product_number'] += $item['product_number'] ;
    }
}
$final = array_values($final);
print_r($final);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [product_id] => 4
            [product_number] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [product_id] => 5
            [product_number] => 8
        )

)
```